# Configuring a workflow to be used with a gated check-in

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, gated-checkin

I am trying to setup a gated check-in policy, but I am running into an issue with my workflow.

In the build definition menu, I select Trigger -> Gated Check-in.
This gives me the error...

"The trigger you selected in the trigger tab cannot be used with the Build Process template you specified on the process tab. (It supports the build reasons Manual, IndividualCI, BatchedCI, Scheduled, ScheduleForced, UserCreated)"

Anyone have an idea as to where I can select which build reasons it supports?

I looked through all the code in the .xaml file, but I did not see anything that stood out as being the issue.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Build Workflow has an argument called SupportedReasons that usually has a default value set.  Try changing the default value of this argument.

Comment: Any side effects? 

I'm looking to change this on the LabTemplate so that I can Build (Standard Template) -> UnitTest -> IntegrationTests (LabTemplate) -> Commit.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by pasting the contents of this xaml file into an existing xaml file that I knew could be used as a Gated Check-in template.

I don't know what the difference is, but this did the trick.